# Convert HTML String to docx Using docx4j Image is not embedded in docx

Tags: java, spring, docx, docx4j, doc

I have HTML string with image base64 and want to convert into DOCX. I am using AlternativeFormatInputPart for convert. if I use XHTMLImporterImpl then I am facing issue in HTML for formating.

```
String html = "<html><body><p>Hello Docx4j</p> <p> <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA..." alt=""/> </p> </body></html>";
htmlToDocx(html, wordMLPackage);

private void htmlToDocx(String htmlString, WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage) throws Exception {
        AlternativeFormatInputPart afiPart = new AlternativeFormatInputPart(new PartName("/hw.html"));
        afiPart.setContentType(new ContentType("text/html"));
        afiPart.setBinaryData(htmlString.getBytes());
        Relationship altChunkRel = documentPart.addTargetPart(afiPart);
        CTAltChunk chunk = factory.createCTAltChunk();
        chunk.setId(altChunkRel.getId());
        documentPart.addObject(chunk);
    }
```

it is converting without image and if I will give image path instead of base64 then it will work but I have multiple image that is coming dynamically on server(linux).
How can I embedded image with AlternativeFormatInputPart.

Please help me to add base64 image.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Is there any other approach to handle this?

Comment: What are the formatting problems with XHTMLImporterImpl?  You can implement your own XHTMLImageHandler if necessary.   Or perhaps you could try an MHTML altChunk.

Comment: What is MHTML altChunk ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML

Comment: Thnaks Json!
I tried XHTMLImporterImpl for convert html to docx but I am not getting fort size and font family from html. Like : 
<p style=\"text-align:justify; font-size:14.5px;\"><span style='font-family:"Helvetica 35 Thin"'>New releases of the template shall be posted on repositories.</span></p>
but in document I am getting "Times New Roman".
How can I solve this issue?